# Android installed base dropped significantly in a span of 2 days. How to find out what happened?

Tags: android, statistics, google-play

I am checking stats for my app on the Android Marketplace (ahem Google Play) and inexplicably the numbers for my app dropped like a rock between the dates of Feb 12 and 14.

[image]

I did not release new versions or anything.  And nothing like this happened on any of my other apps.
What possible explanation is there for such a drop?

Comment: If you look at the daily uninstalls, is there any correlation to language, OS version, country, etc?

Comment: Based on the timing it probably has something to do with change-over from Market to Google Play.  Perhaps the search rankings are different in Play, or maybe some other change is affecting the way your app is presented (or not) to users.

Comment: And most importantly, those numbers have never been particularly reliable. They are also regularly 'adjusted' by Google (up and mostly down) to fit their new algorithms and what not. If you use third party stats (Flurry, etc.), you should compare them to what you see on the Market/Play console.  You can use this link to contact support, but don't count on it too much (Under Help->Contacting support on the console): https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136601

Comment: With all that said, that's not a programming question, so this is probably not the place for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the market has changed how it tracks stats for older phones.

I see a similar drop to yours on February 14th. If I break it down by Android version, I see that 2.3.3 and newer versions stay steady while older versions such as 2.1 show the sudden drop. I also see a clear drop for older phones such as the Motorola Droid while newer phones like the Galaxy S2 don't drop.
[image: Market stats]